# Transform typescript specific statements to javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'd like to do the authentication for my nextjs frontend via a keycloak server. I've found this [great example](https://github.com/react-keycloak/react-keycloak-examples/blob/master/examples/nextjs-app/pages/_app.tsx) about how to do it. Unfortunately the example is written in typescript and I am trying to adjust it so that I can use it in my application written in javascript. Since I don't know much about TS I couldn't figure out how to transform the following two TS statements, so that they run in JS:

```
import type { AppProps, AppContext } from 'next/app'
```

and

```
interface InitialProps {cookies: unknown}
```

since **interface** and **import type** can't be used in JS.

I hope someone can help me out here.
Cheers

Comment: So for the interface I see no reason to import it, as it is compiled away. The type imports however probably need to be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In plain js/React, it will be like this

```
import cookie from "cookie";
import { SSRKeycloakProvider, SSRCookies } from "@react-keycloak/ssr";

const keycloakCfg = {
  url: "http://localhost:8080/auth",
  realm: "Test",
  clientId: "react-test",
};

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, cookies }) {
  return (
    <SSRKeycloakProvider
      keycloakConfig={keycloakCfg}
      persistor={SSRCookies(cookies)}
    >
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SSRKeycloakProvider>
  );
}

function parseCookies(req) {
  if (!req || !req.headers) {
    return {};
  }
  return cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie || "");
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
  // Extract cookies from AppContext
  return {
    cookies: parseCookies(context?.ctx?.req),
  };
};

export default MyApp;
```